# Circuits and Closure Under Reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, circuits

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are languages such that $A\leq_P B$ (many-to-one Karp reduction), and $B\in \mathbf{P/poly}$. How do we prove that $A\in\mathbf{P/poly}$?

Using similar ideas like Cook-Levin (or $P\subseteq \mathbf{P/poly}$), I can show that given $x\in\{0,1\}^n$, there exists a (easily computable) poly-sized circuit that can compute each bit of the reduction, say $R(x)$. The issue for me is that the size of $R(x)$ may depend on $x$ and not only $n$ (since we only require it to be bounded by $\mathrm{poly}(n)$). In such a case, it is not clear how to what input length circuit for the language $B$ to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A \leq_P B$ then since $P \subseteq P/\mathit{poly}$, also $A \leq_{P/\mathit{poly}} B$. This means that there is a function $f \in P/\mathit{poly}$ such that $x \in A \leftrightarrow f(x) \in B$. Since $f \in P/\mathit{poly}$, for every $n$ there is a polynomial size circuit $C$ that computes $f(x)$ for $x$ of length $n$. The circuit needs to have some mechanism for indicating the output length, which might depend on $x$.

Since $C$ has polynomial size, in particular, there are only polynomially many options for the output length, and so if $B \in P/\mathit{poly}$, these circuits can be connected to the outputs of $C$ in order to compute $A$.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, I understand this. My issue is that the size of $f(x)$ may be dependent on $x$ (and not only on $n$), and so it is not clear which sized circuit for $B$ to use after doing this reduction.

Comment: This is not a big problem. I updated my answer, but perhaps it is better if you spent more time on it yourself.